# API4 giving Authorization failed Error

Tags: api, drupal-8

We have local and dev site with drupal 8 + CiviCRM 5.22.0, Installed Contact Layout Editor Extension.

http://localdemo8.com/civicrm/api4. (api4 explorer)

or

http://localdemo8.com/civicrm/ajax/api4 for contact layout api call.

we are getting 500 status with 'Authorization failed' Message in console.

Here is backtrace

```
$Fatal Error Details = array(3) {
  ["message"]=>
  string(20) "Authorization failed"
  ["code"]=>
  NULL
  ["exception"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["API_ExceptionextraParams"]=>
    string(39) "#0 [internal function](): ()
#1 {main}
"
    ["*message"]=>
    string(20) "Authorization failed"
    ["Exceptionstring"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["*code"]=>
    int(0)
    ["*file"]=>
    string(103) "PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php"
    ["*line"]=>
    int(224)
    ["Exceptiontrace"]=>
    string(4877) "#0 PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/API/Kernel.php(150): Civi\API\Kernel->authorize(Object(Civi\Api4\Provider\ActionObjectProvider), Object(Civi\Api4\Action\Entity\Get))
#1 PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/Civi/Api4/Generic/AbstractAction.php(219): Civi\API\Kernel->runRequest(Object(Civi\Api4\Action\Entity\Get))
#2 PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Api4/Page/Api4Explorer.php(26): Civi\Api4\Generic\AbstractAction->execute()
#3 PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(268): CRM_Api4_Page_Api4Explorer->run((Array:2), NULL)
#4 PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#5 PATH/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#6 PATH/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Civicrm.php(88): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#7 PATH/web/modules/contrib/civicrm/src/Controller/CivicrmController.php(75): Drupal\civicrm\Civicrm->invoke((Array:2))
#8 [internal function](): Drupal\civicrm\Controller\CivicrmController->main((Array:2), "")
#9 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(123): call_user_func_array((Array:2), (Array:2))
#10 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Render/Renderer.php(573): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#11 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(124): Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object(Drupal\Core\Render\RenderContext), Object(Closure))
#12 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/EventSubscriber/EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber.php(97): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext((Array:2), (Array:2))
#13 PATH/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(151): Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}()
#14 PATH/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php(68): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#15 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/Session.php(57): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#16 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/KernelPreHandle.php(47): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#17 PATH/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(106): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#18 PATH/web/core/modules/page_cache/src/StackMiddleware/PageCache.php(85): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#19 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/ReverseProxyMiddleware.php(47): Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#20 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/StackMiddleware/NegotiationMiddleware.php(52): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#21 PATH/vendor/stack/builder/src/Stack/StackedHttpKernel.php(23): Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#22 PATH/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/DrupalKernel.php(694): Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, TRUE)
#23 PATH/web/index.php(19): Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
```

Anybody have an idea about this issue ?

Comment: any body have idea ?

Answer (score 2):

Following changes fix the issue,

```
diff --git a/Civi/API/Subscriber/PermissionCheck.php b/Civi/API/Subscriber/PermissionCheck.php
index bc2f18af..282b9faa 100644
--- a/Civi/API/Subscriber/PermissionCheck.php
+++ b/Civi/API/Subscriber/PermissionCheck.php
@@ -76,7 +76,7 @@ class PermissionCheck implements EventSubscriberInterface {
       $event->stopPropagation();
     }
     elseif ($apiRequest['version'] == 4) {
-      if (!$apiRequest->getCheckPermissions()) {
+      if (!$apiRequest->getCheckPermissions() || $apiRequest->isAuthorized()) {
         $event->authorize();
         $event->stopPropagation();
       }
```

Comment: Is there any PR submitted for the above patch?

Comment: It should not be necessary to apply this patch. If you encountered  this in 5.49 like I did, it was fixed by: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/23611